# ScrollLeft not working with hidden div

Tags: jquery, html

Why is that the `ScrollLeft()` property for a specific div doesn't work with hidden div? i.e. when it is set to `display:none` I want to be able to use scrolling left to a particular horizontal place even if the div is hidden.

How can I do that so when the div becomes visible its scroll is already at the place where I set it to?

I have tried multiple versions e.g:

```
function scroll() {
    $('html,body').ready(function () {
        $(".scrollmenu").scrollLeft(500);
    });
}
```

Is there any trick to make it work?

Comment: Need a fiddle or a codepen to be able to make any sort of diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

Try visibility:hidden in your styling instead.